# Verifying the calling of a non-static method of a private static nested class of a static outer class

Tags: java, jmockit

How would I verify that a non-static method of a private nested class has been called?
This is what I have so far:

```
new Verifications() {
    {
        Deencapsulation.invoke(MyClass.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0], "run" );
        times = 4;
    }
};
```

I'm getting this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to invoke non-static method without an instance to invoke it on...
```

Update 1:

@Dennis, I've tried the following, though I'm geting an `NPE`.  I'd like to verify the running of the `run` method against the singleton that's already in the JVM, and not create a new instance of it (as I do in the code below) in order to invoke method `m`.  I tried calling `m.invoke(null)` without success.  Is there a way to verify the invocation (through it's invocation) in jmockit of a non-static method in a private nested class using reflection on the running instance of the outer class?

```
    new Verifications() {
        Class c = MyClass.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0];
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("run");
        //Method m = MyClass.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0].getDeclaredMethod("run", Integer.class, CallableClient.class);

        //Deencapsulation.invoke(MyClass.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0], "run" );
        Class[] a = new Class[] { Integer.class, CallableClient.class};
        Object cc = Deencapsulation.newInstance(c, a);
        //Object cc = Deencapsulation.newInstance(c, withInstanceOf(Integer.class), withInstanceOf(CallableClient.class));
        {
            try {
                System.out.println(MyClass.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0].getName());
                m.invoke(cc);
                times = 3;
```

Update 2:

After trying unsuccessfully to get the method like this: `final Field runnable = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("nestedClassInstance"); runnable.setAccessible(true);` and then using `getDeclaredMethods()` as well as `getMethods()`, i've decided that there's just too much wrong with this approach to continue with this.  I've changed what I'm testing in my test.  Even though I introduced an instance of the inner nested class, I'm assuming that the reason why I can't see the `run` method may be to do with one or all of: the nested nature of its containing class, constructors, and java's behavior/decision to not display instance methods until it could ensure the successful construction of the instance.  Curious to know why I couldn't though, with certainty.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to find out at runtime? It's doable via reflection.

Comment: Yes I am.  What would this approach look like?

Comment: This requires an instance of the outer class, which I'm avoiding, though, may have no choice but to create it: http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/ReflectionUtilities.html. There is no public constructor nor any public method to get the/an instance of the outer class

Comment: I'm going to try something like this: `Field instance = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("_INSTANCE"); instance.setAccessible(true);` and then `m.invoke(instance)`

Comment: I don't know how to get reference to the private static nested class since there is no instance of it...

Comment: The fact that it's a nested class is irrelevant. Since it's an *instance* method, you need to provide an instance on which the method should be called. The JMockit `Deencapsulation` class has two `invoke` overloads which can be used here.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said you wanted to find out if you're trying to invoke a non-static method at runtime, then this bit of reflection should help.

Assuming `m` is the `Method` instance corresponding to your method, then `Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers())` will return true if and only if the method is static, so you can do this check before you actually call `invoke`.
If you don't already have the `Method` object, then something like `Class`'s `getMethod` will be of use to you.

Docs on [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), [`Modifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html), and [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

---

**EDIT:** All of the above is helpful for checking whether or not the method is static before you call it via `invoke`. If you want to use something like jmockit to be able to find out that such a method has been called, then I'm personally wondering how that'll help the `IllegalArgumentException` that you're getting, especially if it's being thrown by `invoke` *because* you're trying to do what the exception message says is not allowed. Even if you could mock it out, that may be covering a deeper issue.

Comment: Correct.  So, I created an instance of the nested class, which I `new` in a method of the outer class.  In my test, I am now getting the nested instance like this: `final Field runnable = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("nestedClassInstance");
        runnable.setAccessible(true);`  I was unable to get the method from `runnable`, though I don' know why.  I printed all the methods using `getDeclaredMethods()` as well as `getMethods()`.

Comment: So, is `getDeclaredMethods()` and `getMethods()` not getting back the method you want? (and I assume you tried `getMethod()` as well)

Comment: I did not try getMethod(), though I may try it once I get some time.  Thanks for your help.